# Stop viewing vote totals

Tags: bug, downvotes, upvotes, user-interface

Just noticed I can click the vote count to see up-vote and down-vote totals. Pretty cool.

Second thing I tried was clicking again to return to the normal, complete total view. Doesn't work.

I'm not sure if that was by design but I think a second click is the correct intuitive attempt, going by the current design, as I haven't yet found any way of going "back" to total count view, aside from refreshing the page or changing my vote.

Comment: And some dups from MSE, including one from way back in 2010 in which Jeff Atwood declined (but really didn't give a great reason why): [Toggling between net votes and plus/minus votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41218/toggling-between-net-votes-and-plus-minus-votes).  This pretty much supports the fact that this is not a bug at all and is the current designed behavior.

Comment: So, Jeff isn't a fan of the overall feature thus the interaction will remain 'broken' - essentially- right? (broken as in non-intuitive)

Comment: Since Jeff is no longer involved with SE, except for what I'm guessing is still some ownership interest (and his moderator-for-life diamond), his opinion doesn't really matter nearly as much as it did then.  And there is lots of things he was passionately against that have been implemented (close vote and flag retraction are 2 that come to mind), so there is hope.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yay! (no offence to Jeff, but the fact that there are a lot of heavily trafficked duplicates means, to me at least, that this is definitely an 'unexpected' UI... feature)